# Compare vectors of vectors of strings in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ (coming from Python) and I am trying to figure out a good way to compare two vectors of different sizes each containing vectors of strings to find matching vectors between them. I tried == but this apparently just compares the iterators and not their contents.

Comment: You mean like `std::set_intersection`, or like `std::find`, or like `std::mismatch`?

Comment: perhaps you forget dereference the iterator? *itr. if you want an answer, don't make us guess, show some code

Comment: Do you just want to test if they are equal (then you can use `==` on the vector objects) or do you want to find any elements that are different?

Comment: `==` should work, agree with @arrows

Comment: P.S. `C++` distinguishes objects and pointers to objects. Iterators act mostly like pointers, so you should dereference them before compare.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to compare the inner vectors? Something like this should work (with gcc 4.7):

```
typedef vector< vector<string> > VectorOfVector;
VectorOfVector v1 = { {"ab", "cd"}, { "ab" } }, v2 = { {"xy"}, {"ab"}};

for(vector<string> & v1item : v1) { 
  for(vector<string> & v2item : v2) { 
    if (v1item == v2item) cout << "found match!" << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> v1 = { {"abc", "012"}, {"xyz", "9810"}};
    vector<vector<string>> v2 = { {"pqr", "456"}, {"abc", "012"}, {"xyz", "9810"}};

    vector<pair<size_t, size_t>> matches;

    for (auto it1 = v1.cbegin(); it1 != v1.cend(); ++it1)
    {
        auto it2 = find(v2.cbegin(), v2.cend(), *it1);
        if (it2 != v2.cend())
        {
            matches.push_back(make_pair(it1 - v1.cbegin(), it2 - v2.cbegin()));
        }
    }

    for_each(matches.cbegin(), matches.cend(), [](const pair<size_t, size_t> &p)
    {
        cout << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
    });
}
```

This prints all the matching index values in both the vectors as pairs. You can read the contents of the matched vectors using the respective vector's [ ] operator.

Answer (score 1):

Find the common sub-vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > data1; // init here
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > data2; // init here

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > results;

    // common sub vectors put in result
    std::set_union(data1.begin(),data1.end(), data2.begin(), data2.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(results));
}
```

But this is probably not answering your underlying question:

Reading between the lines:
You are iterating across both vectors using iterators:

```
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator loop1 = /* Get some part of data1 */;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator loop2 = /* Get some part of data2 */;

  // loop1/loop2 are iterators in-to your vec/vec/string
  // Thus de-referencing them will give you a (const) reference to vec/string
  // Thus you should be able to compare them with `==`

  if ((*loop1) == (*loop2))
  {
      std::cout << "They are the same\n";
  }
```

Comment: The OP has specifically mentioned that both the vectors are of different lengths.

Comment: Hey, I guess it's still buggy. You're checking if the same indices match :(

Comment: No, it's still wrong since the OP wants intersection and not union :)

Comment: Also `set_union` and `set_intersection` works only on sorted containers. Moreover, copying the results could be avoided (as it's a vector of vector of strings, it should be heavy) if the OP needs only the indices of the matching elements.

Comment: @legends2k: Yes it needs to be sorted. Copying as a problem. Maybe. But this is a premature optimization.